# Plant that transforms into a conscious animal

Tags: creature-design

This animal experiences this lifecycle:

Plant $\to$ worm $\to$ flying animal $\to$ humanoid $\to$ plant

It basically never dies and can only be killed if the plant is killed. If it dies in any other stage it will grow into a plant and be reborn.
And, of course, fire totally destroys everything.

Is there a way a plant could store important memories like basic communication, movement, face recognition and language? (For example, being reborn and knowing how to read or how to play an instrument.)

Only the humanoid and flying stages are "conscious". The worm and plant stages just exist mindlessly.

Comment: Your question reminds me of the "Lamb of Tartary": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetable_Lamb_of_Tartary
You might find some additional inspiration there.

Comment: @John Some people are able to split atoms, but I'm not able to split a single question into two... Cause I'm actually asking only one thing. I know that most people here just read the title of the question and the answers, but that's also why most of my questions are so short.

Comment: @John I'm not seeing two questions here. One is "Is there a way a plant could store important memories like basic communication, movement, face recognition and language?". What's the other one?

Comment: How big is the worm? What's the *smallest* stage in the cycle?

Answer (score 17):

It looks like the baseline of what you are looking for is the life cycle of [jellyfishes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jellyfish#Life_cycle) with the difference of not taking place in water.

[image: jellyfish life cycle]

> In most cases, adults release sperm and eggs into the surrounding water, where the unprotected eggs are fertilized and develop into larvae.
>
> The planula is a small larva covered with cilia. When sufficiently developed, it settles onto a firm surface and develops into a polyp. The polyp generally consists of a small stalk topped by a mouth that is ringed by upward-facing tentacles. The polyps resemble those of closely related anthozoans, such as sea anemones and corals. The jellyfish polyp may be sessile, living on the bottom, boat hulls or other substrates, or it may be free-floating or attached to tiny bits of free-living plankton or rarely, fish or other invertebrates. Polyps may be solitary or colonial. Most polyps are only millimeters in diameter and feed continuously. The polyp stage may last for years.
>
> After an interval and stimulated by seasonal or hormonal changes, the polyp may begin reproducing asexually by budding and, in the Scyphozoa, is called a segmenting polyp, or a scyphistoma. Budding produces more scyphistomae and also ephyrae. Budding sites vary by species; from the tentacle bulbs, the manubrium (above the mouth), or the gonads of hydromedusae. In a process known as strobilation, the polyp's tentacles are reabsorbed and the body starts to narrow, forming transverse constrictions, in several places near the upper extremity of the polyp. These deepen as the constriction sites migrate down the body, and separate segments known as ephyra detach. These are free-swimming precursors of the adult medusa stage, which is the life stage that is typically identified as a jellyfish. The ephyrae, usually only a millimeter or two across initially, swim away from the polyp and grow.

You might object that polyps are not plants, however keep in mind that until recent times corals, also made by polyps, were thought to be plants.

And jellyfish, though not being as active as other animals, have their actions defined in their nervous systems, like we do. We are not taught how to breathe or swallow, it's something hard coded in our brains.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like the life cycle of a jellyfish, as L.Dutch pointed out.

Now your stages seem more like it requires extensive metamorphosis, like from humanoid to plant. You may find inspiration in moths and butterflies. The precise biology of metamorphosis in a large scale creature is not in scope of the question, but know that for the insects, [memory is preserved](https://theconversation.com/despite-metamorphosis-moths-hold-on-to-memories-from-their-days-as-a-caterpillar-29859) even when the creature in the cocoon is mostly liquified.

> The metamorphosis involves the breakdown of most of the caterpillar’s tissues before reassembling to form a butterfly. It therefore seems unlikely that butterflies or moths would remember experiences from their caterpillar days. However, scientists have now established that not only can a moth retain memories formed while it was a caterpillar, but that experiences gained during these early stages can have drastic impacts on adult life.

Answer (score 4):

On our current knowledge, information is stored in the synaptic structure between our brain cells.

As plants have no nerve system, they also don't have synapses. But they could - actually nothing avoids it for them, except that it was not developed.

Note, having a brain is evolutionary very costly. Brain cells use many times more energy than even a warm-blooded body (which uses far more than a cold-blooded, which uses far more than a plant).

If the brain does not get its needed oxygen (and blood sugar) needs, the cells start to decay in minutes, and we die.

The plant state will need some mechanism to somehow "hibernate" its nerve cells to make them restart-able in a next stage. There is example even for that - [Tardigrades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardigrade) can survive completely drying up in a hibernated state, and then again revive after they get water.

Giving nerves to plants is probably not too far away even from the GM technology of the today.

There is also [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepidoptera) for an animal with 4 development stages.

Thus, nothing prevents this to work - except that is did not develop, and it will need likely a long development of genetical technology.

The recovery of the brain and the memory after a reborn would be probably not entirely perfect, it would be likely a partial memory loss, like the recovery after a serious brain damage.

Answer (score 1):

There are example in ["Speaker for the Dead"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_for_the_Dead).

Here is how it goes:

```
worm (first life) -> pig (intelligent) (second life) -> tree  (third life)
```

Some tree are intelligent if it is 'ritual kill' and can mate (called father). Please read the book to know more.